# updating firebase node using swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
Posts
-KQ-axCz_VhUV2wFvHeo
   comments
     -KQ-axCz_VhUV2wFv23
        Likes: 1
        userName: 
 -KQ-b2SKufp1lw5-PJyJ
   comments
    -KQ-b2SKufp1lw5-P43534
        Likes: 5
        userName:
```

I have this  structure of data in Firebase and I want to retrieve and update the "Likes" ( increment it) based on some action from the end user. The update needs to get written to Firebase. I am using Swift and this is for an iOS app I am working on. Can someone help me with figuring how I would go about doing this ?

I do have an array right now where I update my data when its created for the first time and then use setvalue on Firebase to upload this data. While retrieving this data from Firebase, again I write it into an array. But I am getting stuck at figuring how I would update one single item remotely ( "Likes" in this case ?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39019868/6297658, Just use this line instead : `currentData.value = currentData.value as! Int + 1`

Comment: Thank You so much. That did it !!!